# What is a word for a "delicate nod"?

Tags: single-word-requests

ex: "Sam [delicately nodded], listening intently and processing a response".

Comment: *inclined his head*?

Comment: I think OP is looking for a repeated slow short nod rather than a tilt. As in processing rather than querying.

Comment: @Z.Dailey Like *bobbing his head*?

Comment: @DanBron that's how I interpreted it. Can't think of a single word for it, let alone something slightly more elegant than the word "bobbed."

Comment: I would say leave it as "delicately nodded" or "nodded gently."

Comment: Sam "acquiesced* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus for 'nod'? What there wasn't good enough and why? Is it a head gesture? Must it be a gesture or just an abstract affirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word but perhaps a more idiomatic expression would be

> Sam [nodded slowly](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22nodded+slowly%22), listening intently and processing a response

Google Books produces  **204,000 hits** for *nodded slowly* compared to 7,800 for [nodded gently](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22nodded+gently%22&tbm=bks), and 1,740 hits for [nodded reflectively](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22nodded+reflectively%22).

Answer (score 0):

[Nod](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nod)

> to move your head up and down as a way of answering “yes” or of showing agreement, **understanding**, or approval

Nodding is clearly a sign that you're **understanding** something or trying to at least.

Depending on the intensity of nodding, it can mean different things but they all come under this definition.

My suggestion is to simply use "nodded gently". Delicately? I'm not so sure. But Google has results for both. Any single word you use instead would sound odd to most people.

Dictionaries may not go into the different kinds of nods. Here's an [article](http://www.study-body-language.com/head-nod.html), for example, briefly talking about "nodding" and body language.